# Installation of openstack on virtual machines (multi-node architecture)

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack

Can I install openstack on 3 different virtual machines with the configurations as listed:
Controller Node: 1 processor, 4 GB memory, and 10 GB storage
Network Node: 1 processor, 4 GB memory, and 20 GB storage
Compute Node: 1 processor, 4 GB memory, and 30 GB storage

I wanted to know if having a physical machine with visualization enabled processor is essential for openstack deployment or one can proceed with virtual machines only. I am asking this because in almost all the documents i have read it suggests to have physical nodes.

I also want to know what difference will it make if i install on a virtual machine(assuming it is possible to install on a VM) & why can i not install openstack on virtual machines(assuming i cannot install openstack on virtual machines)

Please bear in mind that i dont want to install devstack.

Comment: Yes, you can, but stackoverflow is not the right place to ask this. It's not programming related. Also, you can have vms with virtualisation enabled - nested virtualisation is a thing.

Comment: can you tell me where to ask this ? or migrate it to the right site ?

Comment: serverfault.com, or openstack-users mailing list is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess one can install controller and the neutron on VMs.
However, for the compute node you require a physical VM.
A simple configuration could be (as suggested in the openstack docs)
Controller Node: 1-2 CPU, 8GB RAM, 100GB Storage 1 NIC
Neutron Node: 1-2 CPU 2 GB RAM, 50 GB Storage 3 NIC
Compute Node: 2-4 CPU , 8GB RAM, 100+ GB Storage 2 NIC

However i guess(though unsure ) that the compute if has CPU virtualisation enabled, then the compute could also be a VM.

Someone who could specify the implications of running these nodes on a VM compared to physical nodes???

Answer (score 0):

According to Openstack documentattion:

> The following minimum requirements should support a proof-of-concept
> environment with core services and several CirrOS instances:
>
> ```
> Controller Node: 1 processor, 4 GB memory, and 5 GB storage + 2NIC
>
> Compute Node: 1 processor, 2 GB memory, and 10 GB storage + 2 NIC
> ```

For first-time installation and testing purposes, many users select to
build each host as a virtual machine (VM). The primary benefits of VMs
include the following:

```
 One physical server can support multiple nodes, each with almost any number of network interfaces.
```

Very important to say: assure you have 2 Network interface (NIC) on each Node!

check [this Github repository](https://github.com/khansaAmrouni/openstack-yoga-install) for more info, it provides an automated script of Openstack installation on virtualbox with 2 Nodes example, it may helps.